# How to add bordered triangle over a full screen div tag

Tags: html, css

I would like to have a div that is full screen on mobile view-port to have a bordered triangle, I have done this for desktop screens in works, but when I apply the same properties and tweak the numbers, I do get something close to what I want

The HTML is following and a Codepen [here](https://codepen.io/Teebo/pen/NXWNGQ)

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
  <div class=" nav-items-wrapper">
    <div class="navbar-header">
     <a class="navbar-brand" style="margin-top:-8px;" href="/"><img style="width:50%;" src="../../../assets/logos/" alt="">brand</a>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav nav-ul">
     <li class="dem">
        <a href="#">Item 1</a>
     </li>
     <li class="dem">
        <a href="#">Dropdown3</a>
        <ul class="tri" style="visibility: hidden">
            <li class="ic"><a href="#">Option1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Option2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Option3</a></li>
        </ul>
     </li>
     <li class="dem" style="display: none;">
        <a href="#">Item 1</a>
     </li>
    </ul>
</div>
</nav>
<div class="mdiv">
  Mobile view
</div>
```

The one that works is the UL with class of `tri`, this will work on desktop screens, I have hidden it with a inline `visibility: hidden` for now

Here are the corresponding styles for both cases

```
.nav-items-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.nav-ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

@media(max-width:767px) {
  .nav-items-wrapper ul li a{
    font-size: 13px;
  }

  .navbar-default {
    padding-top: 5px;
  }

  .nav-ul {
    width: 40vw;
    justify-content: center;
  }

}

.dem: hover > .tri {
    display:block;
}

.tri {
   // display: none;
    width: 300px;
    border-radius:2px;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #000;
    top: 55px;
    padding: 10px 0;
    right: 0;
    left: auto;
    list-style: none;
}

.tri:after {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: 70px;
    top: -8px;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    content:'';
    border-left: 20px solid transparent;
    border-right: 20px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 20px solid #000000;
}

.tri li {
    white-space: nowrap;
    padding: 7.5px 15px;
}

.mdiv {
  width: 100vw !important;
  max-width: 100vw !important;
  height: 100vh !important;
  background-color: #000;
  right: 0;
  left: auto;
  position: absolute;
} 

.mdiv:after {
    position: absolute !important;
    left: 50% !important;
    margin-left: 25% !important;
    top: 30vh !important;
    width: 0 ;
    height: 0 ;
    content:'';
    border-left: 20px solid green;
    border-right: 20px solid red;
    border-bottom: 20px solid #000000;
    pointer-events: none;
}.navbar-header {
  padding: 10px 10px;
}
```

I am using the Bootstrap nav, I have overwritten the responsive style like the navbar collapse because I do not need them.

The class to look at is the `mdiv` class that I use for the full screen `div`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The div with class was starting from the top so some part of it was under the `navbar`, I have added a `margin-top` to the `mdiv` and adjusted the sizes accordngly and it works fine, thanks, here is the updated, [codePen](https://codepen.io/Teebo/pen/NXWNGQ)